# Change size of listing box locally

Tags: tcolorbox, lstdefinestyle, tcblisting

In the code given below, I get the output:

[image]

How to go about changing the size of the box locally, so that the heading " "cubemaster" Usage" appears on one line instead of two lines?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
numbersep=22pt,
frame=none
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    listing style=mystyle,
    title=#2,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow, right=3cm]{\bfseries{``cubemaster'' Usage}}
cubemaster(13);
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate? [How to fit the width of a tcolorbox to a long title (single line)?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/176964)

Comment: @AlanMunn, I followed your link and put in the code `\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow,right = 3cm]{longtitle={\bfseries{``cubemaster'' Usage}}}`, but that did not work.  Can you tell me how to implement this solution then?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with a `tcolorbox` as a title, grabbing the parameters from the underlying box.

The `colback` option must be set explicitly in order to get the correct background of the `titlebox` environment.

Most likely, the `skin` and `title` facilities of `tcolorbox` provide an easier way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
numbersep=22pt,
frame=none
}


\makeatletter
\newlength{\current@boxwidth}
\newtcolorbox{titlebox}[1][]{enhanced,
  nobeforeafter, 
  left skip=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  boxsep=0pt,
  sharp corners,
  size=minimal,
  #1
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    listing style=mystyle,
    colbacktitle={gray},
   colbacktitle={blue},
  code={\setlength{\current@boxwidth}{\widthof{#2}}\colorlet{outercolbacktitle}{tcbcol@backtitle}},% Calculate the box width
title={\begin{titlebox}[width=\current@boxwidth,colupper=tcbcol@title,colback=outercolbacktitle]#2\end{titlebox}},
    #1,
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow, right=3cm]{{\bfseries``cubemaster'' Usage}}
cubemaster(13);
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution.  If I change the `colbacktitle={blue}`, the title box shows blue, but the title itself shows a gray background.  How to fix this so that the title text background is the same color as the colbacktitle?  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe: I'll take a look

Comment: @Joe: Try again please